# HTML5 Datalist arrow not hiding on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, mobile, browser, datalist

I am trying to hide the native arrow for the datalist because I am using a custom chevron. Doing this works on Desktop Browsers:

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
```

However this does not work on mobile browsers. Can someone help figure out how I can hide the native datalist arrow for mobile browsers?

Comment: Use `diaplay: none` see if it might help

Comment: @Rana tried this as well. It doesn't reflect on mobile browsers